# Mirror github to Gitlab

Tags: github, gitlab

In a local gitlab I created a copy of project nova (https://github.com/openstack/nova).

How do I keep the local nova repo in sync with github, updating maybe once per hour or per day?

I would like a solution similar to what is described here for bitnami:
http://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_GitLab#Keeping_in_sync_with_the_GitLab_repository_at_GitHub

(I used Devstack to install Openstack.)

Comment: Perhaps you could change `How do I keep the local nova repo in sync with github` to: `How do I keep a GitLab copy/mirror of the nova repo in sync with the original repo in GitHub`. That may reduce some ambiguity. For example, that change would render the answer by @DennisKaarsemaker becomes invalid/inappropriate, because that answer keeps a local repository in sync, whereas your question title seems to ask how you can sync the repository in Gitlab instead of locally.

Answer (score 10):

**[GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) now has this feature built-in!**

Since GitLab EE 8.2 [it's supported](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/). ***Hooray!***

> ### [Pulling from a remote respository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/pull.html)
>
> You can set up a repository to automatically have its branches, tags, and commits updated from an upstream repository. 
> ...
>
> When creating a new project, you can enable repository mirroring when you choose to import the repository from "Any repo by URL". Enter the full URL of the Git repository to pull from and click on the **Mirror repository** checkbox.
>
> [image: GitLab auto mirroring]
> <sub>(source: [gitlab.com](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring/repository_mirroring_new_project.png))</sub>

> For an existing project, you can set up mirror pulling by visiting your project's **Settings ➔ Repository** and searching for the "Pull from a remote repository" section. Check the "Mirror repository" box and hit **Save changes** at the bottom.
> ...

Comment: Their example uses gitlab, I followed it exactly except replaced that part with Github, and the updating thing never finishes...

Comment: @MarcusJ Exactly the same here, did you find a solution?

Comment: It's been a while since I had to do this, but I think what I did was use the ssh url in the format of ssh://git@gitlab.com:UserName:RepoName.git

Comment: I just made this work, pulling from github to gitlab is easy if your repo is public, just paste this URL in gitlab settings: `https://github.com/yourGithubUserName/repoName.git`, then choose the Password method in the combobox and leave the password textbox blank

Comment: Pull mirror is now premium only.

Answer (score 5):

If you *never* need local commits, the following recipe will work:

Clone the repo with `--mirror`:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/openstack/nova.git
```

Then in a cronjob, you do this for an hourly update:

```
0 * * * * cd /path/to/nova.git && git fetch
```

The `--mirror` sets up the refspecs in such a way that subsequent fetches will update all local refs, so you don't need to merge the changes in. Of course that does mean that commits pushed to that repo are lost.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it answers the question, which is to get a mirror in GitLab.

Comment: This answer seems to answer the question in the text of the question, but neglects the "question" in the title.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a project with the intention of adding remote mirrors to GitLab.  You can check it out here...

https://github.com/sag47/gitlab-mirrors

Answer (score 0):

Create a cron job to update the repo

Comment: How to setting in gitlab?

Comment: Update your question with the details you require, what you've tried, and what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

In your terminal type `crontab -e` (to edit your crontab) and add a new line at the bottom with the following.

```
* 0 * * * git clone ssh://username@hostname:port/repo
```

It will run a clone every day at midnight.

Comment: I hope it is Incremental updates. no need download all again.